# Finding median in an unsorted array (restricted to use a subroutine that find the quarterly element in linear)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, median

Just like any other median selection problem for an unsorted array but with extra restriction. we are required to use a provided subroutine/helper function, Quart(A,p,r), that finds the 1/4th ordered item in a given subarray in linear time. How can we use this helper function to find the median an array?

Further restriction: 
1. Your solution must be performed in-place (no new
array can be created). In particular, one alternative solution would be
to extend the array to size m so that all the entries in A[n+1, ... ,m] =
1 and m > 2n. After this, you would be able to solve the median
problem in the original array with just one call to the quartile problem
in the extended array. With further restriction, this is not possible.
2. while running the algorithm you may temporarily change elements in the array, e.g., a SWAP changes elements.  But, after the conclusion of your algorithm, all elements in the array must be the same as they were in the beginning (but just as in the randomized selection algorithm taught in class,  they may be in a different order than they were originally).

Since you are not allowed to create new arrays, this means that you are only allowed to modify a small (constant) number of items.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Currently your question cannot really be answered since you are not providing code or a detailed description for `Quart`. Furthermore, it would be good if you could share your previous efforts (i.e. your code) so people actually know what you have tried so far. Please go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [On-topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially the section on homework and how to ask about it since this seems to be a homework problem ("taught in class"). Regards.

Comment: "The median of a set of data is the middlemost number in the set. The median is also the number that is halfway into the set. To find the median, the data should first be arranged in order from least to greatest." So, depending if the array length is even or odd, you will be picking the number of the middle or the two numbers in the middle and divide their sum by 2. In one go, you can swap the one (or two) numbers with the rest so the smallest numbers are on the left of the middle and the highest numbers are on the right. Then, you can do the math.

Answer (score 0):

- Do a pass through the array and find the min and max.
- Call Quart to find the quartile value
- Iterate through the array and add (max - min) + 1 to all values below the quartile. This will move the bottom quarter of the values to the top
- Call Quart again to find the quartile of the new values (which will be the median of the original values)
- Iterate through the array and subtract (max - min) + 1 from all values greater than the max to return the array to its original state

You might need some additional rules to handle special cases e.g. if there are multiple values equal to the quartile.

Comment: I read the question as that `Quart` is the only way to learn about the values of the array. If you can find `min` and `max`, the problem is trivial (unless you know how to use `Quart` to find them).

Comment: @user58697 I guess you could read individual elements using `Quart` with a subarray size of a single element, if that is indeed the restriction.